# How to use buttons to control the focus of other buttons？

Tags: c#, button, controls, focus

I want to use the following four direction buttons to control the focus of the above nine buttons, but after a search, this problem has not been solved, so I come to stackoverflow and hope to get an answer.

Thank you for your answers. Forgive me for being a C# beginner.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Button[,] btns = new Button[3,3] {
                           {button1,button2,button3},
                           {buttonQ,buttonW,buttonE},
                           {buttonA,buttonS,buttonD}};
private int x=0, y=0;

private void buttonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(y>0)
    {
        y--;
        btns[x,y].Focus();
    }
}

private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(y<3)
    {
        y++;
        btns[x,y].Focus();
    }
}

private void buttonUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(x>0)
    {
        x--;
        btns[x,y].Focus();
    }
}

private void buttonDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(x<3)
    {
        x++;
        btns[x,y].Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I can help! But for the record, this site is NOT for asking for something like homework assignment. Such a behavior is "EXTREMELY" discouraged! You have to "at least" show us what you have "tried"! You mentioned "after a search", then show us what search you had ever done!? People here are VERY harsh on that! I myself was a big victim of that! So in the future I hope you could show us more effort. Wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Buttons (1/2/3...A/S/D) in a 2-D Array. Button[3,3].
Then set default Point as 0,0 (Point being a struct having 2 int to identify location).

In Up/Down Click Decrease/Increase the Y coordinate (Decide if you want to do a Pac-Man).. i.e. Pressing down from lowest most position brings you to topmost etc)

In Left/Right click Decrease/Increase X coordinate.

After each click - pick the button from the Button Collection like:

ButtonStore[Point.X, Point.Y]

and then call set focus. (Probably Control.Focus() or something).